# DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea and maximized window

Tags: winapi, dwm

I am trying to build a nice GUI with some glass effect in the client area.

So I implemented it as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb688195%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

I was successful and have nice frame fully of glass, but only as long the window is not maximized. When I maximize the window it is only black :-(

With some googleing and experimenting I figured out, that when I invalidate the the window in response to a `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING` like this:

```
case WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING: {
  WINDOWPOS* pWindowPos = (WINDOWPOS*)lParam;
  if (pWindowPos->flags & SWP_FRAMECHANGED) {
    InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
  }
}
```

I get the glass effect also when I maximize the window.

The odd thing now is that this is only working if I double click on the title bar or this the maximize button on the right top corner of the window. But if I move the window to the top of the screen to let it snap there to maximize the window (Aero Snap) the window turns just black.

Does anyone has a idea how this is done right?

(I am developing under Windows 7 64 bit.)

**Edit:**

I should also mention that I want to remove the standard title bar, I doing so by returning `0` in response to a `WM_NCCALCSIZE` message. Without this everything is working fine.

**Edit:**

A test on another system, which is basically the same was successful. The only notable difference is that there is another graphics card, a AMD Radeon HD 4300 instead of a AMD Radeon HD 5870. Could this be a issue with the driver of the graphics card?

Comment: Read the comment section at the bottom of the article.

Comment: I did. Anything specific you want me to point to?

Comment: Well, did you try the suggested workaround for the complaint that it didn't work properly for maximized windows?

Comment: Could you provide a minimum example(include the source code)? I do create a maximized dwm enabled application before.